# ERROR Invalid Hook call in reactjs typescript project

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty fresh out of the box with react.  Not sure what I need to modify to make this work.  I started my project using the create-react-app as normal. When I have the `<Container>` inside LoginController, I get the ERROR: Invalid Hook.  If I remove it, then it works fine.

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import ClientRouter from './ClientRouter'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>    
      <ClientRouter />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

ClientRouter.tsx

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import LoginController from './controllers/LoginController';
import App from './App';

function ClientRouter()
{
    return (
        <Router>
            <Routes>
                <Route path='/' element={<App/>} />
                <Route path='/login' element={<LoginController/>} />
            </Routes>            
        </Router>
    );
}

export default ClientRouter
```

LoginController.tsx

```
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap"

function LoginController()
{    
    return(
        <Container>
        <h2>Login Page</h2>
        </Container>            
    );
}

export default LoginController
```

Here's more on the ERROR

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: can u add the screenshot of the error, and will be more helpful, if you add a sandbox of the problem for more understanding.

Comment: Not sure what to say.  I created the project here https://codesandbox.io/embed/staging-paper-0zlz6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark and it works fine

Comment: there may be some typo or package version error.